# What is the code to expand excel column width in Coldfusion 8 while exporting?

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Am newbie to coldfusion am using ColdFusion version 8,
Am export my Db recordset datas using,

```
<cfsavecontent variable="report">XXXXX</cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="write"  file = "#fullfile#" output="#report#" nameconflict="overwrite">
```

It's export fine,but I need to expand excel column width.Please Refer my attachment , I got my excel output like my attachment[image: export excel]

Need excel like,
[image: Need excel]

Comment: Since CF did not have spreadsheet functions in version 8, you have to do a lot of work.  Google `apache poi`.  It's a java program that allows you to create files that will work in Excel.  Then learn how to use it and write your code.

Comment: Is there anything else you have tried? If so, share that code.